# Why is it when I strip my string it takes out a character I need in python?

Tags: python, strip

I am new to programming and I was trying to use python to help me with some data. For the most part, when I do a .rstrip('') it does what I want. There are a few times in which when I ask it to print the stripped version, I noticed it took off like an extra 'M' that I did not intend to take out. Am I doing something wrong?

An example of what I use is like this:

```
x = 'SomethingUnwanted_MO-WantedStuff'
f = x.rstrip('SomethingUnwanted_')
print f
```

What I would want in this case is 'MO-WantedStuff'. Every now and again however, when I hit print I will get O-WantedStuff. Am I doing something wrong?

Update: I realized I mistyped as was pointed out to me. I fixed that.

Comment: Sorry but there is nothing to strip from your string, do you want `x = 'SomethingUnwanted_MO-WantedStuff'
f = x.split('_')[1]
f`?

Comment: Sorry I messed up >.> I still am trying to figure this out. It was suppose to say f = x.rstrip('SomethingUnwanted_)

Comment: It's hard to say for certain, but this may be because of a somewhat surprising behavior of `strip`. For example, lots of people think that `"abaxyz".strip("ab")` returns "axyz", but it actually returns "xyz". Just because you listed "a" once, doesn't mean it will only remove one "a".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused as to what `rstrip` does:

```
In [21]:

x = 'SomethingUnwanted_MO-WantedStuff'
f = x.rstrip('SomethingUnwanted_MO-WantedStuff')
f
Out[21]:
''
```

vs:

```
In [18]:

x = 'SomethingUnwanted_MO-WantedStuff'
f = x.split('_')[1]
f
Out[18]:
'MO-WantedStuff'
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html):

> Return a copy of the string with trailing characters removed. If chars
>   is omitted or None, whitespace characters are removed. If given and
>   not None, chars must be a string; the characters in the string will be
>   stripped from the end of the string this method is called on.

**EDIT**

Again you seem to be confused after your edit, from the above the passed in matching sequence is removed from the *right* side in your case nothing wil be removed:

```
In [23]:

x = 'SomethingUnwanted_MO-WantedStuff'
f = x.rstrip('SomethingUnwanted_')
f
Out[23]:
'SomethingUnwanted_MO-WantedStuff'
```

You want `strip` if you want to strip the passed in match from the *left* side:

```
In [24]:

x = 'SomethingUnwanted_MO-WantedStuff'
f = x.strip('SomethingUnwanted_')
f
Out[24]:
'MO-WantedStuff'
```

As shown by @chapelo if you're looking to just remove this string from any position then you can use `replace`:

```
In [25]:

x = 'SomethingUnwanted_MO-WantedStuff'
f = x.replace('SomethingUnwanted_','')
f
Out[25]:
'MO-WantedStuff'
```

Comment: That was a mistake on my part. I mistyped my original code. I fixed that mistake to reflect what I was talking about

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.replace` instead, it is easier:

```
x = 'SomethingUnwanted_MO-WantedStuff'

f= x.replace('SomethingUnwanted_', '')

print (f)   
# MO-WantedStuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

```
x.rstrip('SomethingUnwanted_')
```

First of all, that would remove characters from the *right* of the string `x`, but the unwanted characters are on the *left* of the string in your example. You want plain old `strip` in this situation.

Second, `strip` and `rstrip` do not remove a string, they remove *all the characters* in the string, which is rather different. That is, stripping `'SomethingUnwanted_'` does not remove the string `'SomethingUnwanted_'`, it removes all the `S`s, all the `o`s, all the `m`s , and so on. This is why it removes more than you expected sometimes.

What you want is something more like this:

```
x = 'SomethingUnwanted_MO-WantedStuff'
u = 'SomethingUnwanted_'

if x.startswith(u): x = x[len(u):]
```

You can also do it with a regular expression (`re` module). This way, you can use `^` to make sure it matches only at the beginning. But be careful; regular expressions are their own little mini-language. You are safe using alphanumeric characters and an underscore, like in your example, but some characters have their own meanings in regular expressions, and might not do what you intend.

```
import re

x = re.sub("^SomethingUnwanted_", "", x)
```

Comment: You could use `replace`, but it won't match only at the beginning of the string that way.